# How to make these oblique lines

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make these oblique lines and so that they always rest against this part of the sight with one end, including when changing the screen size?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuu1d.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried as a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG